# bitmap set to imageview is not working android

Tags: android

I am trying to add image to imageview of the listview based on Event type selected by the user,but The image is not reflecting in the imageview . Logcat doesn't shows any error
Pls help me to solve this problem

```
alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("User defined")) {
             showDialog(USER_DEFINED_EVENT_NAME);
        }
        else{
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE, spnView.getSelectedItem().toString());                      
            int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
            if (count==1) {
            String iconType = null;
            if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Birthday")) {
                iconType="birthday_icon.png";
            }
            else if (spnView.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Anniversary")){
            iconType="rings_icon.png";
            }
            InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = getResources().getAssets().open(iconType);
                } catch (IOException e) {                                           
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.v("is......", is.toString());
                Bitmap bit =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                Log.v("bit......", bit.toString());
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bit);
                imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                //finish();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }                       
        }
    });     
    alertDialog=alertBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    return alertDialog;
    }
```

Logcat log

```
is......  android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@42b32d18
bit.....  android.graphics.Bitmap@42b35440
```

Comment: try using an asynctask in order to fill this ImageView. Images can take a lot of time to load if you are downloading them from any URL.

Comment: Where and how the imgView is declared?

Comment: I have made the edit. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to set image to imageview in your activity onResume() :-

```
profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
new DownloadImageTask(profileImage).execute("");
```

Asynctask :-

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
 this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
 String urldisplay = urls[0];
 Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
try {
 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
 mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

float h = mIcon11.getHeight();
float w = mIcon11.getWidth();

float ratio = w / h ;

System.out.println("height is r :- "+h);
System.out.println("width is r :- "+w);
System.out.println("ratio is w/h:- "+ratio);

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}

return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
//bmImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 250, 250, false));
//bmImage.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(result, 250, 250));
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
// CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// RESIZE THE BIT MAP
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);


// RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
return resizedBitmap;
}
}
```